# Final position of a Sprite in cocos 2d based on swipe angle and speed

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

How to get final position of a Sprite in cocos 2d When it swiped at a certain speed and angle ?

Comment: you need to take a look at the ccTouchEnded function and convert the final point to your space coordinates. This will give you a point that then you can use as info. If the question is about final position then speed and angle are not necessary as you want to know only the end position and this is done to you by the "touch enabled" layer where the sprites are created.

Comment: On swipe my sprite is jumping from current location to a new position. The new position is calculated based on speed and angle..I know how to find angle and speed of swipe..Then how to get final position..?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to 'fling' the sprite across the screen? I ask since you are mentioning angle and speed.

If so, you can probably ignore the angle and concentrate more on the length and direction of the swipe since this will give you a vector that you can apply to the sprite.

In `ccTouchBegan` you need to store the initial point coordinate of the touch.

In `ccTouchEnded` you will have the final touch point, so you can use a little pythagoras to calculate the distance between those two points. You now have the length of the swipe.

To calculate the speed you will need to calculate the time between the touch and release and use this to calculate how many units the touch moved per timestamp.

Where the resting point of the sprite will be will depend on how you are applying this force to your sprite. If you are applying the swipe vector to the sprite, I imagine you are updating the sprites position based on its velocity during `update`? To check where the position will be you need to apply the same formula you use there but pass in an arbitrary timestamp to take the place of `delta time`. This will let you see where the object would end up in **T** seconds.

Call it multiple times with increasing values of **T** until the sprite's position is stationary and you have the resting point.